# why my iteration equals to 0 in python scipy fmin_bfgs

Tags: python

I have a problem running the fmin_bfgs optimizer in scipy.
When the sample is less than 1000, I can get a good result.
But when the sample becomes larger, Iterations = 0 and a warning shows: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss'.

Does anybody know that? If you know, please tell me. Thanks very much!

**Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.**

```
     Current function value: 25429.726748
     Iterations: 0
     Function evaluations: 90
     Gradient evaluations: 13
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the quality of the data that causes this problem.